# ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

When creating the foreign key I came across this error. Below is my code.

```sql
create table tblPerson(
  ID int not null primary key,
  Fullname varchar(50) not null,
  Email varchar(50) not null,
  GenderId int
)

create table tblGender ( 
  ID int not null primary key,
  Gender varchar(50) not null
)

alter table tblPerson add constraint tblPerson_GenderId_FK
foreign key (GenderId) references tblGender(ID)
```

Comment: I mean you drop the table and then try to create a FK back to it, does not seem logical does it...  →`drop table tblGender`←

Comment: ignore that part

Comment: Do you have existing data in the tables or they are empty?

Comment: there are data in the tables

Comment: *"there are data in the tables"* Then there is data in the table that doesn't meet the requirements of the foreign key, @FelicioPedro . This is why you should really be creating the keys *before* you start inserting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to identify any "do not align" rows....

I have made the below.

You won't be able to add the FK constraint, if any rows come back from the SELECT query.

I have also removed the hungarian notation for "tbl".  I would advise against it.

```
create table dbo.Person(
ID int not null primary key,
Fullname varchar(50) not null,
Email varchar(50) not null,
GenderId int )

create table dbo.Gender ( 
ID int not null primary key,
Gender varchar(50) not null
)

/* any rows below? your FK creation will fail */
Select *, p.GenderId as 'HoustonWeHaveAProblemValue' from dbo.Person p Where Not Exists (Select 1 from dbo.Gender g where g.ID = p.GenderId)


alter table dbo.Person add constraint Person_GenderId_FK
foreign key (GenderId) references dbo.Gender(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please use the following code to achieve your goal :

**1-First create tblGender:**

```
create table tblGender ( 
  ID int not null primary key,
  Gender varchar(50) not null
)
```

**2-Then create table tblPerson with the relationship between 2 tables since the beginning:**

```
create table tblPerson(
  ID int not null primary key,
  Fullname varchar(50) not null,
  Email varchar(50) not null,
  GenderId int references tblGender(ID)
)
```

works fine.